# Replace Na in column with conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe such as:

```
    COL1 COL2  COL3 
    G1   SP1_1 1
    G1   SP1_2 2
    G1   SP1_3 NA
    G2   SP1_4 1
    G2   SP1_4 1
    G2   SP2_3 NA
    G3   SP1_2 1 
    G4   SP2_3 NA
    G4   SP8_3 NA
    G4   Species_3 NA
    G5   SP9_2 NA 
    G5   SP9_2 NA
```

And I would like simply do replace for each `COL1 groups` the `NA` in `COL3` by a number which is the next number after the highest one in the group.
The duplicated `COL2` within groups should all have the same number.

So I should get:

```
COL1 COL2  COL3 
G1   SP1_1 1
G1   SP1_2 2
G1   SP1_3 3
G2   SP1_4 1
G2   SP1_4 1
G2   SP2_3 2
G3   SP1_2 1 
G4   SP2_3 1
G4   SP8_3 2
G4   Species_3 3
G5   SP9_2 1 
G5   SP9_2 1
```

Here are the data:

```
structure(list(COL1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5"), class = "factor"), 
    COL2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
    7L, 7L), .Label = c("SP1_1", "SP1_2", "SP1_3", "SP1_4", "SP2_3", 
    "SP8_3", "SP9_2", "Species_3"), class = "factor"), COL3 = c(1L, 
    2L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Do you want COL3 to be numbered 1, 2, 3.. etc. for all unique COL1 + COL2 combinations within COL1? In other words, does the existing COL3 numbering contain any useful information we need to keep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: reformulated after question clarified.

On the assumption that COL3 represents a cumulative enumeration of the unique combinations of COL1+COL2 within each COL1, this approach counts the cumulative number of times COL2 has changed within COL1:

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>%
  arrange(COL1, COL2) %>%
  group_by(COL1) %>%
  mutate(COL3 = cumsum(COL2 != lag(COL2, default = ""))) %>%
  ungroup()



# A tibble: 12 x 3
   COL1  COL2       COL3
   <fct> <fct>     <int>
 1 G1    SP1_1         1
 2 G1    SP1_2         2
 3 G1    SP1_3         3
 4 G2    SP1_4         1
 5 G2    SP1_4         1
 6 G2    SP2_3         2
 7 G3    SP1_2         1
 8 G4    SP2_3         1
 9 G4    SP8_3         2
10 G4    Species_3     3
11 G5    SP9_2         1
12 G5    SP9_2         1
```

Comment: hello @Jon Spring , I reloaded the data, your data does not have any NA in COL3 I do not understrand ? And when I use your code on my real data the NA does not change in COL3. And you do not seem to take into accout the fact that duplicated COL2 within COL1 should have the same COL3 values

Comment: So we should (i) add na.rm=T otherwize the max will be NA, and since in some groups there is only NA it will not work ...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and my apologies for misinterpreting the original question.